# Can MySQL do regular expression substitution in an UPDATE?

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-update

I've seen MySQL `SELECT` examples using the `REGEXP` operator for matching.

Is there a way to do regular expression substitution in an `UPDATE`?

If not, what's the simplest method to run a regex substitution on all values in a column?

Feel free to suggest using any programming language or regex implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, no. You can use some cumbersome `REPLACE()` calls, create `UPDATE` statements in a script which does support regex replaces, or use some `UDF`, [this one for instance](http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/)